# Track cursor position relative to element - javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a drawing tool for use on my platform, I've got it working fine using the following code:

```
draw(event.clientX - image.position.left, event.clientY - image.position.top);
```

`image.position` is the position of the image that is being drawn on. Sometimes the image is larger than the height of the container which means you have to scroll down. When you scroll down the pen is drawn further up than the cursor.

```
function draw(x, y) {
    canvas.ctx.beginPath();
    canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    canvas.ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    canvas.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    canvas.ctx.closePath();
    canvas.ctx.stroke();
    lastX = x; lastY = y;
}
```

https://codepen.io/illfre/pen/eYOKKeY

Comment: You can add the mouse listeners directly to the canvas and use `offsetX` and `offsetY` instead of `clientX` and `clientY`, here is an example: https://codepen.io/asdfgdsfad/pen/vYBrVNx

Comment: Have you tested my example ? It seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: Yes and it still works.

Comment: There is a problem with `lastX` and `lastY`, you need to clear those on mouse up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Titus mentioned, you can use the canvas event instead and use `offsetX` & `offsetY`.

```
draw(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
```

I've updated my copepen https://codepen.io/illfre/pen/eYOKKeY